# How can I alter the WordPress query without "overriding" it?

Tags: wordpress

I have a search results page that I want to limit results on i.e. `posts_per_page`. However if I use `query_posts('posts_per_page=6')` I lose the original query.

How do I alter my query without damaging the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`pre_get_posts` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to access/alter the `$query` object. In *functions.php*:

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 6);
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'search_filter');
```

Comment: See you have beaten me to this ;-). Keeping my answer as extra info. Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Never ever use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query object (`$wp_query`) and all functionality that relies on the main query object. It also breaks page functionality. Apart from that, it is slow and reruns queries. `query_posts` should be on top of your most evil list together with functions like `create_function()`, `eval()` and `extract()`.

If you need to alter the main query, always use `pre_get_posts` to do so. Never change the main query with a custom one, it might solve one problem, but it creates many other.

The following will work

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin()
         && $q->is_main_query()
         && $q->is_search()
    ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
    }
});
```

Comment: Extra info for the OP: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts